# "duplicate/on hold" question answered after 1 minute?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, on-hold

This question is a about the following post :

> [JavaScript: Remove last child with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038024/javascript-remove-last-child-with-class)

This post was Marked as **duplicate** at : **11:13:02Z** then received **[another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038024/javascript-remove-last-child-with-class#41038117)** after 1 minute, at **11:14:04Z**.

What I know is that you can't really answer a question once it is on hold, what happening?